# in CoreData Get Specific Column Data from Table

Tags: ios, core-data, identity-column

I am using Core Data for my ios app and I am wondering how would I go about in retrieving an entire column from an entity table? For example I am sql interested in grabbing the primary key from my table.

Comment: You could have just edited the original question which you asked about half an hour before this one. [Retrieve selected column from table in Core Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859327/retrieve-selected-column-from-table-in-core-data)

Comment: Agree with Abizern. You should share some details...

Answer (score 0):

Add Predicate to NSFetchRequest ,in predicate pass your condition.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"coloumn_no = 10"];
```